# is there any website you can upload an mp3 or a youtube song and it will tell you the key of the song?

Tags: music, website

I know if theres sites that you can convert mp3 to mp4, even sites that will increase the volume of the song, there has to be at least a site that it will tell you the key the song is in?

look I already know the song (as written by Mozart himself) is in the key of F major, but I don't know if the orchestra is playing in A = 440mhz or if even they are transposing to a different key entirely.

if its not possible (or there isn't any website with this capability yet) would it at least be possible to isolate a single pitch sung by the soprano, to see what **THAT** pitch is, if that pitch is slightly off, it would be fair to say that the song itself isn't in standart tuning at A = 440?

So say for example you could upload an mp4 of the Queen of the Nights famous aria, and it would tell you if the artist is in fact hitting the F above high C? or would you have to isolote the individual note, and it would tell you if that note is F, or maybe it'd tell you its a little flat or a different pitch entirely?